# Abandoned shopping cart detection

Tags: kentico

I need to add javascript code to show a popup a user abandons a shopping cart. I found [2 solutions](https://docs.kentico.com/k9/on-line-marketing-features/marketing-automation/walkthrough-sending-an-automated-reminder-of-an-abandoned-shopping-cart) for Kentico 7 and Kentico 9, but they don't work for Kentico 8. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use k# Macros to do the trick.  You would do something like the below:

```
CMSContext.Current.SiteObjects.ShoppingCarts.Where("ShoppingCartUserID = "+MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser.UserID+" and ShoppingCartID <> "+ECommerceContext.CurrentShoppingCart.ShoppingCartID).Count > 1
```

Put that in a Javascript web part to then alert.  Use System -> Macros -> Console to test first though till you get it right!

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't the article you linked to work in K8? I don't see anything in it that looks like it is only in K9.

There is a [module](https://www.predictes.com/en/Kentico-Abandoned-Cart-Module) for 8.2, but it's not free.

This [article](http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/e-commerce-custom-macro-in-online-marketing-process-abandoned-shopping-cart) may be the other one you were referring to that was in K7. It should work for 8 I believe, some of the api calls may have changed in the code presented, so you may have to look up what the new ones are. The concept should still work.